# What is the distinction between "relationships" and "differences" (particularly in the context of group differences on a numeric attribute)?

Tags: correlation, t-test, terminology, group-differences, association-measure

What is the distinction between a relationship and a difference in the context of statistics - if you have a nominal variable and an interval variable, when should you use a correlation to measure the relationship, rather than a t-test or an ANOVA?

I'm not after the usual 'what is your question about - relationships or differences' (although I obviously appreciate the importance), but rather what is it about the data or the constructs that I should know to make this decision.

If for example you have males and females and their intelligence scores. Is there a statistical/conceptual reason why a t-test is better here than a point-biserial correlation?

This is probably going to be an obvious question. To be honest though, I don't feel like I've ever really understood the distinction, so perhaps some of you can articulate it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association (or "correlation") and difference are two sides of the same coin. Difference between groups by some quantitative characteristic can be reasoned as the association between variables "group" and "characteristic". **Eta** coefficient, also called correlation ratio, is the proper association measure between a nominal variable and a scale variable, and is therefore the other side of the coin for ANOVA or t-test. In fact, Eta is used as the effect-size measure (i.e. standardized measure of the size of the difference) in ANOVA. Association measures which vary from 0 to 1 or -1 to 1 are often used as effect size measures. Point-biserial correlation is equal to Eta when there are 2 groups. Point-biserial correlation is just Pearson *r*.